# jquery map with conditions

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to add a condition to a map function?

I'm trying to get the computer names of workstations that are win7 and ready, omitting the win10 machines.

Is there any good way to get the 2 workstations using the map command or should I look for a different approach?

```js
$('#get').click(function() {
  var grids = $('.highlight').map(function() {
    return this.id;
  }).get().join();
  console.log(grids);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <th>Workstation</th>
  <th>Version</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <tr>
    <td id="mac1" class='highlight'>mac1</td>
    <td>win7</td>
    <td class='status'>ready</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mac2</td>
    <td>win7</td>
    <td class='status'>not ready</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="mac3" class='highlight'>mac3</td>
    <td>win10</td>
    <td class='status'>ready</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mac4</td>
    <td>win10</td>
    <td class='status'>ready</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mac5</td>
    <td>win7</td>
    <td class='status'>not ready</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='mac6' class='highlight'>mac6</td>
    <td>win7</td>
    <td class='status'>ready</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class='button' id='get'>Get</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mLf5az63/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
$('#get').click(function () {
  var grids = $('.highlight').map(function () {
        var type = $(this).next('td')[0].innerText;
        var status = $(this).next('td').next('td')[0].innerText;
        if(type == 'win7' && status == 'ready') {
            return this.id;
        }
   }).get().join();
   console.log(grids);
});
```

I have updated your JS fiddle as well, you can test there.

https://jsfiddle.net/yov7ugjx/2/

Comment: Looks like the best answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`.map` is probably a good solution, combined with `.filter`, if you don't have too many elements. This is even possible without using jQuery at all like so.

```js
document.getElementById('get').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const grids = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr'))
    .map(line => {
      // Get the first cell with the id or undefined if not available
      const id = (line.querySelector('td:nth-child(1)') || {}).id;
      // Get the second cells content
      const version = (line.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)') || {}).innerText;
      // And lastly the status
      const status = (line.querySelector('.status') || {}).innerText;

      // Check version and status and return the id
      if (version === 'win7' && status === 'ready') {
        return id;
      }

      // Otherwise something falsy
      return null;
    })
    // Only return item when it is tru'ish
    .filter(item => item);
  console.log(grids);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <th>Workstation</th>
  <th>Version</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <tr>
    <td id="mac1" class='highlight'>mac1</td>
    <td>win7</td>
    <td class='status'>ready</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mac2</td>
    <td>win7</td>
    <td class='status'>not ready</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="mac3" class='highlight'>mac3</td>
    <td>win10</td>
    <td class='status'>ready</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mac4</td>
    <td>win10</td>
    <td class='status'>ready</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mac5</td>
    <td>win7</td>
    <td class='status'>not ready</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='mac6' class='highlight'>mac6</td>
    <td>win7</td>
    <td class='status'>ready</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id='get'>Get</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach you could do is to put the children details on the `tr` as data elements.  Then after finding the highlighted elements, you can find their parent rows, filter on the ones you want, and then perform your map.

```js
$('#get').on('click', function() {
  var grids = $('.highlight')
    .closest('tr')
    .filter(function(){
      return this.dataset.os === 'win7' && this.dataset.status === 'ready'
    })
    .map(function() {
      return this.dataset.id;
    }).get().join();
    
  console.log(grids);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <th>Workstation</th>
  <th>Version</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <tr data-id="mac1" data-os="win7" data-status="ready">
    <td id="mac1" class='highlight'>mac1</td>
    <td>win7</td>
    <td class='status'>ready</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id="mac2" data-os="win7" data-status="not ready">
    <td>mac2</td>
    <td>win7</td>
    <td class='status'>not ready</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id="mac3" data-os="win10" data-status="ready">
    <td id="mac3" class='highlight'>mac3</td>
    <td>win10</td>
    <td class='status'>ready</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id="mac4" data-os="win10" data-status="ready">
    <td>mac4</td>
    <td>win10</td>
    <td class='status'>ready</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id="mac5" data-os="win7" data-status="not ready">
    <td>mac5</td>
    <td>win7</td>
    <td class='status'>not ready</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id="mac6" data-os="win7" data-status="ready">
    <td id='mac6' class='highlight'>mac6</td>
    <td>win7</td>
    <td class='status'>ready</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class='button' id='get'>Get</div>
```